# Is "It is supposed to do smth in case of..." correct?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

Writing documentation I want to describe an action which a user is expected to do in case of some situation. Is it correct to say it the next way: "It is supposed to do ... in case of ...", where "it" doesn't point a subject directly, but only means the generic expectation from any who will read the documentation?

Additionally if it is correct, would negation form "it is supposed NOT to do ..." be correct?

Can "supposed" in these cases be replaced with "expected"?

What about "it may not be acceptable to do ..."?

Comment: Do you mean 'It is obligatory to take action if X occurs'?

Comment: These examples make for vague instructions. Isn't the **system** or the **application** *doing* this activity?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, Yosef, in that particular case it is not an obligatory action, but it's like advice from the creators how to handle a situation. It is possible to deviate from the proposed behavior by system design.

Comment: ... So "If X occurs, you are strongly advised to do A."

Comment: Thank you @EdwinAshworth, I see the point of your answer. Sorry, but what about the concrete phrases I mentioned in the subject, are they grammatically incorrect? I used these phrases but was remarked that they are not correct. However, I have heard them several times before. Maybe they are not commonly used?

Comment: No, you can't use _it is supposed to_ in that way; the subject of the sentence has to be a person.

Comment: Extraposition is not possible with 'It is supposed [not] [to stay in the room when a fire breaks out'  for 'One is not supposed to stay in a room where a fire has broken out.' However, 'It is supposed that people will not stay in a room where a fire has broken out' is acceptable English (and practice).

Comment: Thank you all for the answers.